# triangle similarity problem.

Tags: geometry

$2ac=bc$
find the ratio ( $K$ ) 
what is the ratio of their area?
[image]I found out it is $2$ or $1/2$
is it true?

if the question isn't clear, make sure to notify me, I will make an effort to make it understandable

Comment: How did you find out that is is $2$ or $1/2$? Why not just include that explanation in your post so no one has to re-do this exercise for you?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the area of left triangle $A_1$ and the right triangle $A_2$.

**A quick guide**:

As the angles: $\angle ADC = \angle BYC$, all angles of triangle are 2 by 2 equal so the triangles are similar (not equal) because $\dfrac{AC}{BC}=\dfrac{1}{2}$, so the ratio of each vertex are equal to $2$ or $1/2$ hence $\dfrac{A_1}{A_2}=\big(\dfrac{1}{2}\big)^2=\dfrac{1}{4}$

**The comprehensive solution**:

Since they both are right-angled triangles, we have:

$\displaystyle A_1=\frac{AC \times CD}{2}$

$\displaystyle A_2=\frac{BC \times CY}{2}$

$\displaystyle \dfrac{A_1}{A_2}=\dfrac{\frac{AC \times CD}{2}}{\frac{BC \times CY}{2}}=\frac{AC}{BC}\frac{CD}{CY}=\frac{CD}{2\times CY}$

$K=\dfrac{A_1}{A_2}$ or $\dfrac{A_2}{A_1}$

> Now if $CD=CY$ then $K=\dfrac12$ or $2$, **but** $\require{cancel} CD\cancel{=}CY!$

As the angles: $\angle ADC = \angle BYC$, the triangles are similar (not equal), hence $\dfrac{AC}{BC}=\dfrac{CD}{CY}=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$K=\dfrac{CD}{2\times CY}=\dfrac{1}{4}$ or $\dfrac{2\times CY}{CD}=4$

Answer (score 0):

You marked the angles at $f$ and $g$ (or $d$ and $y$) are equal.  So the triangles are similar.
If one has vertical edge half the other, their bases will also be in ratio 2 to 1.